# Spring Convert enity manager getResultList results to JSON

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, jpa

I'm quite new to spring and I'm using spring `entitymanager.createquery` to make query and get the result from database.

So when make a http get this method executes to get all the patient name

```
    public List<PatientModel> fetchallpatients (){
        Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery("select * from patient p ");
       List <PatientModel> patientList=q.getResultList();
        System.out.println(patientList);
        return patientList;
    }
```

it is returning

> ```
> [[
>     1,
>     "patientname",
>     "patientphone",
>     "patientgender",
>     "patientinsurance",
>     "patientage",
>     "patientdiagnosis",
>     "patientaddreq",
>     "patientemr"
> ],
> [
>     2,
>     "test",
>     "patientphone",
>     "patientgender",
>     "patientinsurance",
>     "patientage",
>     "patientdiagnosis",
>     "patientaddreq",
>     "patientemr"
> ],
> [
>     3,
>     "react",
>     "12312",
>     "male",
>     "react",
>     "56",
>     "dsa",
>     "ads",
>     "das"
> ],
> [
>     4,
>     "sign",
>     "asd",
>     "male",
>     "react",
>     "56",
>     "Diagnose 2",
>     "Ventilator",
>     "on"
> ],
> [
>     5,
>     "good",
>     "3213",
>     "male",
>     "react",
>     "56",
>     "Diagnose 3",
>     "ICU",
>     "on"
> ] ]
> ```

Front end I'm using react and I need this data to be in JSON format.

I have a POJO class for corresponding table:

```
package io.login.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class PatientModel  {

    String patientname;
    String patientage;
    String patientgender;
    String patientinsurance;
    String patientphone;
    String patientaddreq;
    String patientemr;


    public String getPatientname() {
        return patientname;
    }

    public void setPatientname(String patientname) {
        this.patientname = patientname;
    }

    public String getPatientage() {
        return patientage;
    }

    public void setPatientage(String patientage) {
        this.patientage = patientage;
    }

    public String getPatientgender() {
        return patientgender;
    }

    public void setPatientgender(String patientgender) {
        this.patientgender = patientgender;
    }

    public String getPatientinsurance() {
        return patientinsurance;
    }

    public void setPatientinsurance(String patientinsurance) {
        this.patientinsurance = patientinsurance;
    }

    public String getPatientphone() {
        return patientphone;
    }

    public void setPatientphone(String patientphone) {
        this.patientphone = patientphone;
    }

    public String getPatientdiagnosis() {
        return patientdiagnosis;
    }

    public void setPatientdiagnosis(String patientdiagnosis) {
        this.patientdiagnosis = patientdiagnosis;
    }

    public String getPatientaddreq() {
        return patientaddreq;
    }

    public void setPatientaddreq(String patientaddreq) {
        this.patientaddreq = patientaddreq;
    }

    public String getPatientemr() {
        return patientemr;
    }

    public void setPatientemr(String patientemr) {
        this.patientemr = patientemr;
    }

    String patientdiagnosis;

    public PatientModel(String patientname, String patientage, String patientgender, String patientinsurance, String patientphone, String patientdiagnosis, String patientaddreq, String patientemr) {
        this.patientname = patientname;
        this.patientage = patientage;
        this.patientgender = patientgender;
        this.patientinsurance = patientinsurance;
        this.patientphone = patientphone;
        this.patientdiagnosis = patientdiagnosis;
        this.patientaddreq = patientaddreq;
        this.patientemr = patientemr;
    }


}
```

But I need the result like

```
    { { "patientname":"xyz" 
"patientphone":"xyz" 
"patientinsurance":"xyz" 
"patientgender":"xyz" 
"patientdiagnosis":"xyz" 
"patientaddreq":"xyz" ... so on

    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you are returning `List<String[]>` and expect it to be a JSON list of your POJO?

change your method to return what is expected, like:

```
  @Transactional
  public List<PatientModel> fetchallpatients () {
      Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery("select * from patient p ");
      List <PatientModel> patientList = q.getResultList();
      System.out.println(patientList);
      return patientList;
  }
```

Comment: It is still the same, it is returning List not json. I forgot to add that in the question. I will edit it now.